# "The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties" on child class

Tags: c#

I have a class `A` with 5 constructors:

- from `IEnumerable<A>` (e.g. `A(new A[] {A1, A2})`)
- from `A[]` using `params` (shortcut to the previous one, e.g `A(A1, A2)`)
- from `Vector<Complex>`
- from `IEnumerable<Complex>` (converts enumerable to vector and calls the previous one, e.g. `A(new Complex[] {Complex1, Complex2})`)
- from `Complex[]` using `params` (shortcut to the previous one, e.g. `A(Complex1, Complex2)`)

And a class `B` that extends `A` with 3 more specific constructors:

- from `Complex a, Complex b`
- from `double a, double b, double c, double d`
- from `double a, double b`

Code below:

```
public class A
{
    public A(params A[] array) : this((IEnumerable<A>)array) { }

    public A(IEnumerable<A> enumerable)
    {
        //
    }

    public A(params Complex[] array) : this((IEnumerable<Complex>)array) { } // Breaks shit

    public A(IEnumerable<Complex> enumerable) : this(Vector<Complex>.Build.DenseOfEnumerable(enumerable)) { }

    public A(Vector<Complex> vector)
    {
        //
    }
}

public class B : A
{
    public B(Complex a, Complex b)
    {
        //
    }

    public B(double a, double b, double c, double d)
    {
        //
    }

    public B(double a, double b)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Upon adding the constructor with `Complex[]` to `A`, the following error appears on all three constructors of `A`:

`Error  CS0121  The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'A.A(params A[])' and 'A.A(params Complex[])'`

I thought constructors were not inherited, how can a new constructor in the parent class interfere with the ones in the child class? How to solve the issue?

And is the pattern I'm using to allow for various equivalent types of input (e.g. both `A(Complex1, Complex2)`, `A(ComplexArray)`, and `A(ComplexVector)`) good practice or should I do it differently?

Comment: You say: `Upon adding the constructor with Complex[] to B` but I do not see such a constructor in `B`. Did you mean `A`?

Comment: You're right, thanks for noticing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Constructors run in order from base class first to inherited class last.

```
public B(Complex a, Complex b)
{
    //
}
```

is equal to

```
public B(Complex a, Complex b) : base()
{
    //
}
```

The compiler is trying to find a constructor for base type (A) which can accept no parameters.
Because of the params keyword there are two candidates:

```
public A(params A[] array) : this((IEnumerable<A>)array) { }
```

and

```
public A(params Complex[] array)  { }
```

You are receiving the error because the compiler cannot decide which one should be used. To fix this you can rewrite constructors for the B class to use base class constructors:

```
public B(Complex a, Complex b) : base(a, b)
{
    //
}
```

Comment: Thank you, didn't realize that the base constructor was called even when not expressly specified.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood properly your problem.

You cannot override constructor of base class. If `B` inherited from `A` and if both classes have the constructor with same signatures it will not works. Constructor of base class is always executed, but if you still need to implement two constructors with same you can use [base](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfw7t1ce.aspx) keyword.

In you r case it should be:

```
public class B : A
{
    public B(Complex a, Complex b) : base(a, b)
    {
        // Do some code here
    }

    public B(double a, double b, double c, double d)
    {
        //
    }

    public B(double a, double b)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Both constructors are still executed but now you can write logic in constructor of `B` class.